# Teleport player into minecart or boat

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How would I teleport a player into a minecart or boat?
And I don't mean in the same block as, I mean actually *in* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually possible with a BE-exclusive command, `/ride`. Here is the basic syntax that you'll need:

```
ride <riders: target> start_riding <ride: target> [teleportRules: TeleportRules] [howToFill: FillType]
```

- `riders`: The targets you want to begin riding on top of the ride.
- `ride`: The ride that you want `riders` to begin riding on top of.

Sample command:

```
ride @p start_riding @e[type=minecart] teleport_rider
```

Comment: Woah, I didnt know see this existed, 1.16.100 seems to have added a lot of “secret” stuff

Comment: Thank you. Can you ride any mob, even another player?

Comment: @EmojiMaker Unfortunately no, you are restricted to combinations available in survival Minecraft.

Comment: The `FillType` is `teleport_rider`. How would you teleport the boat/minecart to the player?

Comment: @EmojiMaker `teleport_ride`, of course!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378545/258509), it’s better**

Sorry, I'm afraid you can’t. You can however, just tell the player to right-click through `/tellraw` and hope they listen:

```
/tellraw @p {"rawtext":[{"text":"Get in the boat."}]}
```

Comment: This is a snarky comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: The quotes are wrong, this doesn't seem like it would help a lot as it answers a different question OP didn't ask, and "hope they listen" seems sarcastic

Comment: @Penguin The smart quotes don't work in my 1.16

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Oh, I didn't see the first sentence. Apologies

Comment: Oh sorry, my iPad by default has these quotes `”` and I have to do the hold and select thing to change them